How to set a timer for this circuit?
I have this circuit however I need to make a timer that works for 2 - 2.30 hours, so I have this circuit here:

But I need to know how much should R1 and C1 be approximately to fulfill this job?
Note: inverting input voltage is 455 mV approximately.

Do you mean 2.15 hrs +/- 0.15 hrs or do you mean a timing range of 2-2.3 hours with a tighter tolerance?

2 and a half hours? sound like a job for CD4060 perhaps combined with a monostable.

Sorry didn't clarify I meant to say it goes for 2 hours or 2 and half hours

The capacitor discharge equation:
$$
V_C = V_o \ e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}
$$
where \$V_0\$ is the initial voltage of the capacitor which is 5 VDC, \$C\$ is the capacitance and \$R\$ is the load resistance.
After 2 hrs i.e. \$t=7200 \ \text{seconds}\$, the capacitor voltage \$V_C\$ should be 0.5V or less. Therefore,
$$
0.5=5 \ e^{7200/RC}
$$
Solving this for \$RC\$, so the time constant \$RC\$ should be \$RC = 3126 \ \text{s}\$. For 2.5 hrs it'd be \$RC = 3900 \ \text{s}\$.
So you need to select a \$C\$ and a \$R\$ that makes the \$RC\$ time constant between the two values above. For example, \$C = 1000 \mu\$ gives \$R=\mathrm{3M9}\$.
There are two important things to consider:

If you select a small \$C\$ with a large \$R\$ like the example above, the bias currents of the op amp may come into play, especially when the capacitor voltage approaches the stop (low threshold) value, ~0.5V. So the timing may change a lot. If you make the selection the other way around you'll end up with quite a few number of large capacitors as well as relatively higher loss across the discharge resistor. \$C = 47000\mu\$ (10x 4700μ in parallel) and \$R=82\mathrm{k\Omega}\$ look an acceptable pair to me.
With a large \$C\$ (e.g. at least 10000μ), during charging of the capacitor (i.e. button press) very large inrush currents may flow so the source should be able to provide this level of high peak currents, otherwise the capacitor may not charge up to 5 VDC. The peak of the inrush currents will be determined by the ESR of the capacitor pack (expect a few mΩ, up to 10 mΩ), the contact resistance of the button, and the total wiring resistance. To mitigate this, a series resistor after the button can be placed but this will slow down the charging, especially for a large \$C\$.


But isn't RC would equal 3900 for C=1000μ and R=3M9?

don't worry about the biasing current it worked for me with a lm324 4.7μf and 18MΩ and made a timer for approximate to 3 minutes.

@HazardousVoltage But isn't RC would equal 3900 for C=1000μ and R=3M9? yes, 3900 seconds corresponds to 2.5 hrs, check the calculation above. Also, with RC = 3900 it becomes easier to pick standard values such as 3M9 and 1000u.
